# Remote connection to mysql, allow *

Tags: mysql

I have seen the use of:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 255.112.324.12
```

to allow remote access for a single IP. How would I allow remote access from mysql to all IPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the bind-address from localhost, `127.0.0.1`, to `0.0.0.0`:

```
# /etc/mysql/my.cnf
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to allow it for all IP's then I think you don't need a `bind-address` at all? Try commenting it out

```
#bind-address    = 255.112.324.12
```